# How to explain the advantages of refactoring spaghetti code?

Tags: language-agnostic, refactoring

I have been tasked to refactor a tool full of duplicated code, coupled modules (even the author of the code is afraid of changing anything since he doesn't know what it may impact) and an overly complex database (250+ queries that could be replaced with about 20).

The project clients are only aware that the tool is hard to maintain and to change, but have no technical expertise.

How can I explain in simple terms the advantages of the new tool having a smaller code base, reusing code, decoupling components and adhering to code conventions?

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

You almost answered your own question :)

The point of refactoring is to make code easier, i.e. cheaper, to change. ("Maintain" is just a subset of "change".)

It's right there in [Fowler's definition of refactoring](http://www.refactoring.com/): "noun: a change made to the internal structure of software to make it easier to understand and cheaper to modify without changing its observable behavior". And the point of "easier to understand" is to make it cheaper to modify. No-one pays programmers to just sit around understanding things and doing nothing with their understanding.

Bad code costs money in many ways:

- When you need to fix a bug in or add a feature to your poorly factored program, it takes you extra time to understand the impact of your change. That time costs money.
- When you change your poorly factored program you are more likely to do a bad job: to introduce a regression, or to fix a bug only partially (if it's in duplicated code), or to not implement your new feature as well as you would have if the code was easier to work with. All those things lower the quality of your product, which costs you money due to

  - decreased sales or (if it's an internal tool) less use of the tool and consequent loss of the efficiency that the tool is intended to provide
  - more bug fixes and other support costs
- You might decide to not make some changes at all due to the risk of regression or other cost of change. Again, that lowers the quality of your product, which costs you money.

You can even put a cash value on the quality of your codebase by estimating the cost of reinvestigating the code every time you change it, the cost of lost sales or usage, the cost of additional support due to bugs and the opportunity cost of not making changes that you would make if it were easier to do so. Balance that against the cost of refactoring.

Side note: You didn't specifically mention testing, so I should mention for completeness that refactoring implies automated testing, which like refactoring is an investment with its own costs and benefits. You would certainly be mad to do any significant refactoring without tests.